# Django websockets on Azure App service

Tags: websocket, azure-web-app-service

Do I have any option running django using websockets on azure app service.

I've used Django-Channels and succeed on my local computer using redis (asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer). But when the app is deployed on azure I got Error 404 on my ws connection. In the log there is a wrong url coming from FastCgi Handler.

Here is my error in console:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://mySite.azurewebsites.net/chat/a/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Any suggestion or hint?

Thanks,
Kristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Pusher (now they have a free version) following this post:
[How to use Pusher with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315378/how-to-use-pusher-with-django)

If you are using Azure there is a service for pusher which allow you to host your Pusher in Azure and use your credits for paying and still have access to pusher website for monitoring.

BR,
Kristian