# PusherBadRequest Unknown Auth_Key

Tags: python, django, real-time, pusher

I'm building this app so that whenever I update an user in the update view, The other view with user's detail displays a change notification.

I'm getting PusherBadRequest Unknown Auth_Key, But all the configs are right as you can see in my settings.py.

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'pusherable'
]

PUSHER_APP_ID = "340365"
PUSHER_KEY = "bbc35fac8ee3918e0048"
PUSHER_SECRET = "[REDACTED]"


pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
  app_id=PUSHER_APP_ID,
  key=PUSHER_KEY,
  secret=PUSHER_SECRET,
  cluster='us2',
  ssl=True
)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


    class Users(models.Model):
        GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
        )

        RELATIONSHIP_STATUS = (
            ('Single', 'solteiro'),
            ('Engaged', 'engaged'),
        )

        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
        Birth_Date = models.DateTimeField('Data de Nascimento')
        Relationship_Status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices= RELATIONSHIP_STATUS)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from.models import Users
from .forms import UpdateUser
from pusherable.mixins import PusherDetailMixin, PusherUpdateMixin


class User(PusherDetailMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Users
    template_name = "Users.html"


class UsersUpdate(PusherUpdateMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Users
    form_class = UpdateUsers
    template_name = "UpdateUsers.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

**Templates**

**Users.html**

```
{% load pusherable_tags %}
{% pusherable_script %}
{% pusherable_subscribe 'update' object %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script>
    function pusherable_notify(event, data) {
        alert(data.user + "has begun to " + event + " " + data.model);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
Name: {{ object.name }} <br>
Sex: {{ object.sex }} <br>
Relationship: {{ object.Relationship_Status }}
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UpdateUsers.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, I redacted your secret, because that string would allow others to send messages on your behalf. You can create a new token on https://dashboard.pusher.com/apps/340365/keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [django-pusherable](https://github.com/pusher/django-pusherable) library is unaware of Pusher clusters, and configures your app to use the `mt1` cluster. Your app is on the `us2` cluster, which does not know about your app.

This is a bug in django-pusherable, and we'll fix it promptly. I'll get back to you when we've released a fix. (I work for Pusher!)

Comment: @Goun2 No problem, btw we're working on a fix here https://github.com/pusher/django-pusherable/pull/10

Comment: I changed the cluster to mt1 and it worked great, but the notifications doesn't appear when I update, and one more time thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I have another question about this Django-Pusherable.
In my app I'm getting the notification when I open the view not when I update the object in the view, Can't pusher send the notification only when an action happen ? such as update or delete.

Comment: @Goun2 this is now released as 0.2.0 on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pusherable

Comment: @Goun2 could you expand on your problems in more detail as new questions?